# Is there a file size limit or extension limit in wagtail?

Tags: django, wagtail

I have a very simple model (Product) which is used as an InlinePanel in a page.

Product has a FileField which works fine as long as I upload small files, but as soon as I upload a large file (>5MB), I somehow get an CSRF error. Both on local and on production.

It is not an issue with nginx max upload size.

Is there a file size limit or extension limit in wagtail?

Comment: 'an CSRF error'. What error? Please be specific.

Comment: "CSRF verification failed. Request aborted." In the traceback: "Forbidden (CSRF token missing or incorrect.): /admin/pages/4/edit/"

Comment: That has nothing to do with upload size. It says: 'CSRF token missing or incorrect'.    Use your debug tools to inspect the form. It should have a csrf token input. Check if you have CsrfViewMiddleware in your middleware settings. Read https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/csrf/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this comes baked into wagtail. If you add the following setting to your settings.py (or whatever your main settings file is), you'll be able to restrict upload sizes.

```
WAGTAILIMAGES_MAX_UPLOAD_SIZE = 15 * 1024 * 1024   # 15mb
```

The docs briefly cover this, too. Here's the link: http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.1.1/advanced_topics/settings.html#maximum-upload-size-for-images

If you need to change the file size from 15mb to anything else, just change that `15` in the settings line to the number of mb you want to limit it to.

Comment: Is this only for images? Because in my case the uploads work for images, but don't work for mp3's...

Comment: Yes I believe this is for images only.

Answer (score 0):

In some cases, you might have configured a temporary directory for large file 
downloads.

In my case this was:

```
 FILE_UPLOAD_TEMP_DIR = str(ROOT_DIR('tmp'))
```

If this directory is not created, you cannot upload large files, but small files will work fine. Simply create the directory locally and on production.

This bug is extremely hard to debug, as the wagtail admin interface will simply say that the upload fails, and somehow it will even yield a CSRF error.

Comment: I can reproduce the problem and creating the tmp dir works. Maybe we should open an issue in the Django tracker. Raising an unrelated error like that seems a bug.

Comment: That makes sense. I just spent 3 hours debugging this (+ 3 hours in the past few days). I've never raised an issue in the django tracker. Do you want to go ahead and raise it?