# Wagtail Documents: Large file size (>2GB) upload fails

Tags: python, django, wagtail

I'm trying to upload a file using the built in wagtaildocs application in my Wagtail application. I've setup my Ubuntu 16.04 server was setup with the Digital Ocean tutorial methods for Nginx | Gunicorn | Postgres

Some initial clarifications:

1. In my Nginx config I've set `client_max_body_size` 10000M;
2. In my production settings I have the following lines:
   `MAX_UPLOAD_SIZE = "5242880000"
   WAGTAILIMAGES_MAX_UPLOAD_SIZE = 5000 * 1024 * 1024`
3. My file type is a `.zip`
4. This a production test at this point. I've only implemented a basic wagtail application without an additional modules.

So as along as my File size is below 10Gb I should be fine from a configuration stand point unless I'm missing something or am blind to a typo.

I've already tried adjusting all the configuration values even to unreasonably large values. I've tried using other file extensions and doesn't change my error.

I assume this has to do with a TCP or SSL connection being closed during the session. I've never encountered this problem before so I'd appreciate some help.

Here is my error message:

```
Internal Server Error: /admin/documents/multiple/add/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/wgarlock/Git/wagtaildev/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
psycopg2.DatabaseError: SSL SYSCALL error: Operation timed out


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/wgarlock/Git/wagtaildev/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Users/wgarlock/Git/wagtaildev/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/Users/wgarlock/Git/wagtaildev/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Users/wgarlock/Git/wagtaildev/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py", line 44, in _wrapped_view_func
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/wgarlock/Git/wagtaildev/lib/python3.7/site-packages/wagtail/admin/urls/__init__.py", line 102, in wrapper
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/wgarlock/Git/wagtaildev/lib/python3.7/site-packages/wagtail/admin/decorators.py", line 34, in decorated_view
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/wgarlock/Git/wagtaildev/lib/python3.7/site-packages/wagtail/admin/utils.py", line 151, in wrapped_view_func
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/wgarlock/Git/wagtaildev/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/vary.py", line 20, in inner_func
    response = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/wgarlock/Git/wagtaildev/lib/python3.7/site-packages/wagtail/documents/views/multiple.py", line 60, in add
    doc.save()
  File "/Users/wgarlock/Git/wagtaildev/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 741, in save
    force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
  File "/Users/wgarlock/Git/wagtaildev/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 779, in save_base
    force_update, using, update_fields,
  File "/Users/wgarlock/Git/wagtaildev/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 870, in _save_table
    result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)
  File "/Users/wgarlock/Git/wagtaildev/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 908, in _do_insert
    using=using, raw=raw)
  File "/Users/wgarlock/Git/wagtaildev/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/wgarlock/Git/wagtaildev/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1186, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
  File "/Users/wgarlock/Git/wagtaildev/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1335, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/wgarlock/Git/wagtaildev/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 99, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/wgarlock/Git/wagtaildev/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 67, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/Users/wgarlock/Git/wagtaildev/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 76, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/Users/wgarlock/Git/wagtaildev/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/wgarlock/Git/wagtaildev/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/Users/wgarlock/Git/wagtaildev/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.DatabaseError: SSL SYSCALL error: Operation timed out
```

Here are my settings

```
### base.py ###
import os

PROJECT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(PROJECT_DIR)
SECRET_KEY = os.getenv('SECRET_KEY_WAGTAILDEV')

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/deployment/checklist/


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'home',
    'search',

    'wagtail.contrib.forms',
    'wagtail.contrib.redirects',
    'wagtail.embeds',
    'wagtail.sites',
    'wagtail.users',
    'wagtail.snippets',
    'wagtail.documents',
    'wagtail.images',
    'wagtail.search',
    'wagtail.admin',
    'wagtail.core',

    'modelcluster',
    'taggit',

    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'storages',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',

    'wagtail.core.middleware.SiteMiddleware',
    'wagtail.contrib.redirects.middleware.RedirectMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'wagtaildev.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'templates'),
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'wagtaildev.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'HOST': os.getenv('DATABASE_HOST_WAGTAILDEV'),
        'USER': os.getenv('DATABASE_USER_WAGTAILDEV'),
        'PASSWORD': os.getenv('DATABASE_PASSWORD_WAGTAILDEV') ,
        'NAME': os.getenv('DATABASE_NAME_WAGTAILDEV'),
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/

STATICFILES_FINDERS = [
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
]

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'static'),
]

# ManifestStaticFilesStorage is recommended in production, to prevent outdated
# Javascript / CSS assets being served from cache (e.g. after a Wagtail upgrade).
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#manifeststaticfilesstorage
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'django.contrib.staticfiles.storage.ManifestStaticFilesStorage'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'


# Wagtail settings

WAGTAIL_SITE_NAME = "wagtaildev"

# Base URL to use when referring to full URLs within the Wagtail admin backend -
# e.g. in notification emails. Don't include '/admin' or a trailing slash
BASE_URL = 'http://example.com'

### production.py ###

from .base import *

DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['wagtaildev.wesgarlock.com', '127.0.0.1','134.209.230.125']

from wagtaildev.aws.conf import *

EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'

MAX_UPLOAD_SIZE = "5242880000"
WAGTAILIMAGES_MAX_UPLOAD_SIZE = 5000 * 1024 * 1024
FILE_UPLOAD_TEMP_DIR = str(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'tmp'))
```

Here are my Nginx settings

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name wagtaildev.wesgarlock.com;
    client_max_body_size 10000M;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/wesgarlock/run/wagtaildev.sock;
    }
}
```

Comment: Try the [answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51332838/is-there-a-file-size-limit-or-extension-limit-in-wagtail) maybe?

Comment: I tried this and it had no effect. I made a new droplet and a new wagtail project with the minimum settings to perform this action. I'm trying to upload a 1.9Gb and 2.3Gb file now. I'll post the output.

Answer (score 2):

I was never able to solve this problem directly, but I did come up with a hack to get around it.

I'm not a Wagtail or Django expert so I'm sure there is a proper solution to this answer, but anyway here's what I did. If you have any recommendations on improvement feel free to leave a comment.

As a note this is really documentation to remind me what I did as well. There are many redundant lines of code at this point (05-25-19) because I Frankenstein'ed a lot of code together. I'll edit it down overtime.

Here are the tutorials I Frankenstein'ed together to create this solution.

1. https://www.codingforentrepreneurs.com/blog/large-file-uploads-with-amazon-s3-django/
2. http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.1.1/advanced_topics/documents/custom_document_model.html
3. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html
4. https://medium.com/faun/summary-667d0fdbcdae
5. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/loading-browser-credentials-federated-id.html
6. https://kite.com/python/examples/454/threading-wait-for-a-thread-to-finish
7. http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/daemonizing.html#usage-systemd

There may be a few others, but these were the principles.

Okay here we go.

I create an app called "files" and then a Custom Document models a models.py file. You need to specify WAGTAILDOCS_DOCUMENT_MODEL = 'files.LargeDocument' in your settings file. The only reason I did this was to track the behavior I was changing more explicitly. This custom Document model simply extended the standard Document Model in Wagtail.

```
#models.py

from django.db import models
from wagtail.documents.models import AbstractDocument
from wagtail.admin.edit_handlers import FieldPanel
# Create your models here.
class LargeDocument(AbstractDocument):

    admin_form_fields = (
        'file',
    )
    panels = [
        FieldPanel('file', classname='fn'),
    ]
```

Next you'll need to create a wagtail_hook.py file with following content.

```
#wagtail_hook.py
from wagtail.contrib.modeladmin.options import (
    ModelAdmin, modeladmin_register)
from .models import LargeDocument
from .views import LargeDocumentAdminView


class LargeDocumentAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    model = LargeDocument

    menu_label = 'Large Documents'  # ditch this to use verbose_name_plural from model
    menu_icon = 'pilcrow'  # change as required
    menu_order = 200  # will put in 3rd place (000 being 1st, 100 2nd)
    add_to_settings_menu = False  # or True to add your model to the Settings sub-menu
    exclude_from_explorer = False # or True to exclude pages of this type from Wagtail's explorer view

    create_template_name ='large_document_index.html'

# Now you just need to register your customised ModelAdmin class with Wagtail
modeladmin_register(LargeDocumentAdmin)
```

This allows you to do 2 things:

1. Create a new menu item for uploading Large Documents while maintaining your standard document menu item with its standard functionality.
2. Specify a custom html file for handling large uploads.

Here is the html

```
{% extends "wagtailadmin/base.html" %}
{% load staticfiles cache %}
{% load static wagtailuserbar %}
{% load compress %}
{% load underscore_hyphan_to_space %}
{% load url_vars %}
{% load pagination_value %}

{% load static %}
{% load i18n %}

{% block titletag %}{{ view.page_title }}{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

    {% include "wagtailadmin/shared/header.html" with title=view.page_title icon=view.header_icon %}
          <!-- Google Signin Button -->
          <div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn" data-theme="dark">
          </div>
          <!-- Select the file to upload -->

          <div class="input-group mb-3">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/input.css'%}"/>
            <div class="custom-file">
              <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="file" name="file">
              <label id="file_label" class="custom-file-label" style="width:auto!important;" for="inputGroupFile02" aria-describedby="inputGroupFileAddon02">Choose file</label>
            </div>
            <div class="input-group-append">
              <span class="input-group-text" id="file_submission_button">Upload</span>
            </div>
            <div id="start_progress"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="progress-upload">
            <div class="progress-upload-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: 100%;" aria-valuenow="100" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
          </div>
{% endblock %}

{% block extra_js %}
    {{ block.super }}
    {{ form.media.js }}
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
    <script src="https://sdk.amazonaws.com/js/aws-sdk-2.148.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/awsupload.js' %}"></script>
{% endblock %}

{% block extra_css %}
    {{ block.super }}
    {{ form.media.css }}
    <meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="847336061839-9h651ek1dv7u1i0t4edsk8pd20d0lkf3.apps.googleusercontent.com">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

{% endblock %}
```

I then created some objects in views.py

```
#views.py
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.
import base64
import hashlib
import hmac
import os
import time
from rest_framework import permissions, status, authentication
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from .config_aws import (
    AWS_UPLOAD_BUCKET,
    AWS_UPLOAD_REGION,
    AWS_UPLOAD_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
    AWS_UPLOAD_SECRET_KEY
)
from .models import LargeDocument
import datetime
from wagtail.contrib.modeladmin.views import WMABaseView
from django.db.models.fields.files import FieldFile
from django.core.files import File
import urllib.request
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from .tasks import file_creator

class FilePolicyAPI(APIView):
    """
    This view is to get the AWS Upload Policy for our s3 bucket.
    What we do here is first create a LargeDocument object instance in our
    Django backend. This is to include the LargeDocument instance in the path
    we will use within our bucket as you'll see below.
    """
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]
    authentication_classes = [authentication.SessionAuthentication]

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        The initial post request includes the filename
        and auth credientails. In our case, we'll use
        Session Authentication but any auth should work.
        """
        filename_req = request.data.get('filename')
        if not filename_req:
                return Response({"message": "A filename is required"}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
        policy_expires = int(time.time()+5000)
        user = request.user
        username_str = str(request.user.username)
        """
        Below we create the Django object. We'll use this
        in our upload path to AWS.

        Example:
        To-be-uploaded file's name: Some Random File.mp4
        Eventual Path on S3: <bucket>/username/2312/2312.mp4
        """
        doc_obj = LargeDocument.objects.create(uploaded_by_user=user, )
        doc_obj_id = doc_obj.id
        doc_obj.title=filename_req
        upload_start_path = "{location}".format(
                    location = "LargeDocuments/",
            )
        file_extension = os.path.splitext(filename_req)
        filename_final = "{title}".format(
                    title= filename_req,
                )
        """
        Eventual file_upload_path includes the renamed file to the
        Django-stored LargeDocument instance ID. Renaming the file is
        done to prevent issues with user generated formatted names.
        """
        final_upload_path = "{upload_start_path}/{filename_final}".format(
                                 upload_start_path=upload_start_path,
                                 filename_final=filename_final,
                            )
        if filename_req and file_extension:
            """
            Save the eventual path to the Django-stored LargeDocument instance
            """
            policy_document_context = {
                "expire": policy_expires,
                "bucket_name": AWS_UPLOAD_BUCKET,
                "key_name": "",
                "acl_name": "public-read",
                "content_name": "",
                "content_length": 524288000,
                "upload_start_path": upload_start_path,

                }
            policy_document = """
            {"expiration": "2020-01-01T00:00:00Z",
              "conditions": [
                {"bucket": "%(bucket_name)s"},
                ["starts-with", "$key", "%(upload_start_path)s"],
                {"acl": "public-read"},

                ["starts-with", "$Content-Type", "%(content_name)s"],
                ["starts-with", "$filename", ""],
                ["content-length-range", 0, %(content_length)d]
              ]
            }
            """ % policy_document_context
            aws_secret = str.encode(AWS_UPLOAD_SECRET_KEY)
            policy_document_str_encoded = str.encode(policy_document.replace(" ", ""))
            url = 'https://thearchmedia.s3.amazonaws.com/'
            policy = base64.b64encode(policy_document_str_encoded)
            signature = base64.b64encode(hmac.new(aws_secret, policy, hashlib.sha1).digest())
            doc_obj.file_hash = signature
            doc_obj.path = final_upload_path

            doc_obj.save()



        data = {
            "policy": policy,
            "signature": signature,
            "key": AWS_UPLOAD_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
            "file_bucket_path": upload_start_path,
            "file_id": doc_obj_id,
            "filename": filename_final,
            "url": url,
            "username": username_str,
        }
        return Response(data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

class FileUploadCompleteHandler(APIView):
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]
    authentication_classes = [authentication.SessionAuthentication]

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        file_id = request.POST.get('file')
        size = request.POST.get('fileSize')
        data = {}
        type_ = request.POST.get('fileType')
        if file_id:
            obj = LargeDocument.objects.get(id=int(file_id))
            obj.size = int(size)
            obj.uploaded = True
            obj.type = type_
            obj.file_hash
            obj.save()
            data['id'] = obj.id
            data['saved'] = True
            data['url']=obj.url
        return Response(data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

class ModelFileCompletion(APIView):
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]
    authentication_classes = [authentication.SessionAuthentication]

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        file_id = request.POST.get('file')
        url = request.POST.get('aws_url')
        data = {}
        if file_id:
            obj = LargeDocument.objects.get(id=int(file_id))
            file_creator.delay(obj.pk)
            data['test'] = 'process started'
        return Response(data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

def LargeDocumentAdminView(request):
    context = super(WMABaseView, self).get_context(request)
    render(request, 'modeladmin/files/index.html', context)
```

This views goes around the standard file handling system. I didn't want to abandon the standard file handling system or write a new one. This is the reason why I call this hack and a non ideal solution.

```
// javascript upload file "awsupload.js"
var id_token; //token we get upon Authentication with Web Identiy Provider
function onSignIn(googleUser) {
  var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
  // The ID token you need to pass to your backend:
  id_token = googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token;
}

$(document).ready(function(){

  // setup session cookie data. This is Django-related
  function getCookie(name) {
      var cookieValue = null;
      if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
          var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
          for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
              var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
              // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
              if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
                  cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                  break;
              }
          }
      }
      return cookieValue;
  }
  var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');
  function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
      // these HTTP methods do not require CSRF protection
      return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
  }
  $.ajaxSetup({
      beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
          if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
              xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
          }
      }
  });
  // end session cookie data setup.

  // declare an empty array for potential uploaded files
  var fileItemList = []

  $(document).on('click','#file_submission_button', function(event){
      var selectedFiles = $('#file').prop('files');
      formItem = $(this).parent()
      $.each(selectedFiles, function(index, item){
          uploadFile(item)
      })
      $(this).val('');
      $('.progress-upload-bar').attr('aria-valuenow',progress);
      $('.progress-upload-bar').attr('width',progress.toString()+'%');
      $('.progress-upload-bar').attr('style',"width:"+progress.toString()+'%');
      $('.progress-upload-bar').text(progress.toString()+'%');
  })
  $(document).on('change','#file', function(event){
      var selectedFiles = $('#file').prop('files');
      $('#file_label').text(selectedFiles[0].name)
  })



  function constructFormPolicyData(policyData, fileItem) {
     var contentType = fileItem.type != '' ? fileItem.type : 'application/octet-stream'
      var url = policyData.url
      var filename = policyData.filename
      var repsonseUser = policyData.user
      // var keyPath = 'www/' + repsonseUser + '/' + filename
      var keyPath = policyData.file_bucket_path
      var fd = new FormData()
      fd.append('key', keyPath + filename);
      fd.append('acl','private');
      fd.append('Content-Type', contentType);
      fd.append("AWSAccessKeyId", policyData.key)
      fd.append('Policy', policyData.policy);
      fd.append('filename', filename);
      fd.append('Signature', policyData.signature);
      fd.append('file', fileItem);
      return fd
  }

  function fileUploadComplete(fileItem, policyData){
      data = {
          uploaded: true,
          fileSize: fileItem.size,
          file: policyData.file_id,

      }
      $.ajax({
          method:"POST",
          data: data,
          url: "/api/files/complete/",
          success: function(data){
              displayItems(fileItemList)
          },
          error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
              alert("An error occured, please refresh the page.")
          }
      })
  }

  function modelComplete(policyData, aws_url){
      data = {
          file: policyData.file_id,
          aws_url: aws_url
      }
      $.ajax({
          method:"POST",
          data: data,
          url: "/api/files/modelcomplete/",
          success:
          console.log('model complete success')  ,
          error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
              alert("An error occured, please refresh the page.")
          }
      })
  }

  function displayItems(fileItemList){
      var itemList = $('.item-loading-queue')
      itemList.html("")
      $.each(fileItemList, function(index, obj){
          var item = obj.file
          var id_ = obj.id
          var order_ = obj.order
          var html_ = "<div class=\"progress\">" +
            "<div class=\"progress-bar\" role=\"progressbar\" style='width:" + item.progress + "%' aria-valuenow='" + item.progress + "' aria-valuemin=\"0\" aria-valuemax=\"100\"></div></div>"
          itemList.append("<div>" + order_ + ") " + item.name + "<a href='#' class='srvup-item-upload float-right' data-id='" + id_ + ")'>X</a> <br/>" + html_ + "</div><hr/>")

      })
  }

  function uploadFile(fileItem){
          var policyData;
          var newLoadingItem;
          // get AWS upload policy for each file uploaded through the POST method
          // Remember we're creating an instance in the backend so using POST is
          // needed.
          $.ajax({
              method:"POST",
              data: {
                  filename: fileItem.name
              },
              url: "/api/files/policy/",
              success: function(data){
                      policyData = data
              },
              error: function(data){
                  alert("An error occured, please try again later")
              }
          }).done(function(){
              // construct the needed data using the policy for AWS
              var file = fileItem;
              AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.WebIdentityCredentials({
                  RoleArn: 'arn:aws:iam::120974195102:role/thearchmedia-google-role',
                  ProviderId: null, // this is null for Google
                  WebIdentityToken: id_token // Access token from identity provider
              });
              var bucket = 'thearchmedia'
              var key = 'LargeDocuments/'+file.name
              var aws_url = 'https://'+bucket+'.s3.amazonaws.com/'+ key
              var s3bucket = new AWS.S3({params: {Bucket: bucket}});
              var params = {Key: key , ContentType: file.type, Body: file, ACL:'public-read', };
              s3bucket.upload(params, function (err, data) {
                  $('#results').html(err ? 'ERROR!' : 'UPLOADED :' + data.Location);
                }).on(
                  'httpUploadProgress', function(evt) {
                    progress = parseInt((evt.loaded * 100) / evt.total)
                    $('.progress-upload-bar').attr('aria-valuenow',progress)
                    $('.progress-upload-bar').attr('width',progress.toString()+'%')
                    $('.progress-upload-bar').attr('style',"width:"+progress.toString()+'%')
                    $('.progress-upload-bar').text(progress.toString()+'%')

                  }).send(
                    function(err, data) {
                      alert("File uploaded successfully.")
                      fileUploadComplete(fileItem, policyData)
                      modelComplete(policyData, aws_url)
                    });
          })
  }


})
```

Explanation of .js and .view.py interaction

First an Ajax call with file information in the head creates the Document object, but since the file never touches the server a "File" object is not created in the Document object. This "File" object contained the functionality I needed so I needed to do more. Next my javascript file uploads the file to my s3 bucket using the AWS Javascript SDK. The s3bucket.upload() function from the SDK is robust enough to upload files up to 5GB, but with a few other modifications not included it can upload up to 5TB (aws limit). After the file is uploaded to the s3 bucket, my final API call occurs. The final API call triggers a Celery task that downloads the file to a temporary directory on my remote server. Once the file exists on my remote server the File objects is created and saved to document model.

The task.py file that handles the download of the file from S3 bucket to the remote server and then creates & saves the File object to the document file.

```
#task.py
from .models import LargeDocument
from celery import shared_task
import urllib.request
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.core.files import File
import threading

@shared_task
def file_creator(pk_num):
    obj = LargeDocument.objects.get(pk=pk_num)
    tmp_loc = 'tmp/'+ obj.title
    def downloadit():
        urllib.request.urlretrieve('https://thearchmedia.s3.amazonaws.com/LargeDocuments/' + obj.title, tmp_loc)

    def after_dwn():
         dwn_thread.join()           #waits till thread1 has completed executing
         #next chunk of code after download, goes here
         send_mail(
             obj.title + ' has finished to downloading to the server',
             obj.title + 'Downloaded to server',
             'info@thearchmedia.com',
             ['wes@wesgarlock.com'],
             fail_silently=False,
         )
         reopen = open(tmp_loc, 'rb')
         django_file = File(reopen)
         obj.file = django_file
         obj.save()
         send_mail(
             obj.title + ' has finished to downloading to the server',
             'File Model Created for' + obj.title,
             'info@thearchmedia.com',
             ['wes@wesgarlock.com'],
             fail_silently=False,
         )

    dwn_thread = threading.Thread(target=downloadit)
    dwn_thread.start()

    metadata_thread = threading.Thread(target=after_dwn)
    metadata_thread.start()
```

This is process needs to run in Celery because downloading large files takes time and I didn't want to wait around with a browser open. Also inside of this task.py is a python thread() which forces the process to wait until the file is successfully downloaded to the remote server. If you are new to Celery here is the start of their documentation (http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/master/getting-started/introduction.html)

Also I've added some email notifications for confirmation that the processes completed.

Final note I created a /tmp directory in my project and setup a daily delete of all files to give it the tmp functionality.

```
crontab -e
find ~/thearchmedia/tmp -mtime +1 -delete
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suspect that the exception `psycopg2.DatabaseError SSL SYSCALL error: Operation timed out` will happen if the droplet is running out of memory.

Try to create a swap partition or extend your memory.

[Creating a swap partition](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-swap-space-on-ubuntu-16-04)

Comment: I'll try this out and get back to you.