# How to correctly handle Wagtail Large File Uploads

Tags: python-3.x, nginx, wagtail

I have searched for an definite answer online and on stackoverflow, but I have not found a **clear step-by-step way to handle uploading large files (50MB+) to a wagtail CMS website**.

My setup is nginx, gunicorn, postgresql on a ubuntu server.

When trying to upload a large file from the "documents" section of the admin (e.g: /admin/documents/multiple/add/), the progressbar moves as when uploading a file as normal, but then it has an error in the admin: *"Sorry, upload failed."*
I am basically having the same problem as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56105090/wagtail-documents-large-file-size-2gb-upload-fails), only without that specific error message.

I have set `client_max_body_size` to 100000M (nginx) and the `MAX_UPLOAD_SIZE` setting (wagtail/django) to a large amount as well.

How can I resolve the issue and successfully upload my large files (.zip and .xyz) to the wagtail website? Any help and/or suggestions are appreciated. Thanks.